# Invalid directory object -FAILED ORA-29280

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors

Well i have created a procedure to export the result of a query in a csv file, the procedure is created successfully but when i execute it this error appears, i have created the directory successfully , also the path is correct but it seems there is something missing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_csv IS

    p_filename utl_file.file_type;
    p_column   VARCHAR2(4000);
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
        ivs_fic,
        ivs_issuer_tin
    FROM
        fs.fis_invoices;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSIDE CREATE_CSV ');

    p_filename := utl_file.fopen(' CSV_DIR ', 'file.csv', 'w', 4000);
```

Here is the part of the code where the procedure stucks.

Comment: Did you really use a quoted identifier and have spaces in the name when you created the directory object? If not you probably meant: `utl_file.fopen('CSV_DIR', 'file.csv', 'w', 4000);`  The `'CSV_DIR'` has to exactly match the directory name as it appears in the data dictionary (e.g. in `all_directories`).

Comment: Can you also include your `CREATE DIRECTORY` DDL command?